# 3.5mm 'IR' output to USB HID input - Does such a device exist?

Tags: usb, infrared, hid

In my media cabinet I have a HDMI matrix that does IR output over a 3.5mm jack to an emitter. In the same cabinet I have multiple PC's with IR to USB HID receivers to translate to keypresses.

This seems like an necessary step going to and from IR in the middle, I'm curious if there exists a device that can take the 'IR' output from that 3.5mm jack and go straight to a USB HID device?

If so what would this device be called I'm having no luck at all finding one!

Comment: You might be able to hack an existing receiver to inject the signal directly.

Comment: Part of the issue is that the source cable is probably carrying a series of 40 KHz pulses the *envelope* of which needs to be decoded (and typically inverted).  The widely available and inexpensive zero-configuration component which does this is an IR receiver "blob" - it's not that other solutions can't be made, but going through an IR emitter and receiver is the simplest and cheapest, and gets you galvanic ground isolation for free!

Comment: What is the "a HDMI matrix", and what output information does it convey?